# How to index a PDF book into several documents in Solr

Tags: solr

All:

I am new to Solr, currently I am indexing a very large PDF book, if I just simply index it as a single document into Solr, it seems useless for searching. What I want to do is indexing it by page or paragraph or by chapter(either way is ok). Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks